# Split list in multiple small lists after input value is set - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input field, a button and a unordered list with lots of elements inside it. My idea is to enter a value in the input filed, hit the button and after that the list splits into multiple **ul**-s, where the number of **li** in a small **ul** should be the value entered in the input.

This is what my HTML looks like

```
        <input type="text" class="input-value" onfocus="this.select();" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Enter number':this.value;" value="Enter number"/>
        <button type="button" id="push" onclick="appendInput()">push me</button>

        <div id="todo"></div>
        <div id="lists">
            <ul id="big-list">
                <li>List item no. 1</li>
                <li>List item no. 2</li>
                <li>List item no. 3</li>
                <li>List item no. 4</li>
                <li>List item no. 5</li>
                <li>List item no. 6</li>
                <li>List item no. 7</li>
                <li>List item no. 8</li>
                <li>List item no. 9</li>
                <li>List item no. 10</li>
                <li>List item no. 11</li>
                <li>List item no. 12</li>
                <li>List item no. 13</li>
                <li>List item no. 14</li>
            </ul>           
        </div>
```

This is the jQuery part

```
    function appendInput() {
        $('#todo').html($('.input-value').val());
        var inputValue = $("#todo").html();
        var $bigList = $('#big-list'), group;
        while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(inputValue)').remove()).length){
            $('<ul/>').append(group).appendTo('#lists');
        }
    }
```

I can't see why it's not working. Can some one point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your 'inputValue' is not variable.

```
while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(' + inputValue + ')').remove()).length){
            $('<ul/>').append(group).appendTo('#lists');
        }
```

Comment: That was the mistake, my bad, thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use Javascript to manipulate the data. This will be easier to maintain, but it's also a better choice if you care about the performances since you manipulate the DOM less frequently.

```
var list = [
    'List item no. 1',
    'List item no. 2',
    'List item no. 3',
    'List item no. 4',
    'List item no. 5',
    'List item no. 6',
    'List item no. 7',
    'List item no. 8',
    'List item no. 9',
    'List item no. 10',
    'List item no. 11',
    'List item no. 12',
    'List item no. 13',
    'List item no. 14'
];

function updateLists() {
    var i = 0,
        html = [],
        slice = parseInt($('.input-value').val());
    while (i < list.length) {
        html.push(
            '<ul><li>', 
            list.slice(i, i + slice).join('</li><li>'), 
            '</li></ul>'
        );
        i += slice;
    }
    $('#lists').html(html.join('')); // a single DOM query
}
```